# Server produced pkpass file error not matching certs

Tags: php, wallet

I am getting an error when creating a pkpass file from a server. The error is:

"The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified."

I've double checked the certs and ensured the passtypeID and teamID both match the cert. When I create a pkpass locally using the same cert, the pass comes out fine. If I unzip the pass, the json all looks ok. I can view the pass in safari but if I try and update to wallet or email to my iPhone, it won't load to wallet, same if I try and drag it into the simulator. Needing help as everything I've looked into seems to be fine??

Comment: Check that you are using the latest Apple WWDR certiificate.

Comment: Haha that was it, thanks heaps for your help